# Dockerfile custom commands/directives

Tags: dependency-injection, docker, containers, dockerfile

I've been reading through the Docker documentation and can't seem to work out if its possible to create a custom command/directive. Basically I need to make an HTTP request to external service to retrieve some assets that need to be included within my container. Rather than referencing them using Volumes I want to effectively inject them into the container during the build process, a bit like dependancy injection.

Comment: if you meant to download the files from Dockerfile from http url, you can try this. "RUN wget http://www.urlABC.com/abc.gz"

Comment: This gets me some of the way, however I will need to run a combination of HTTP GET's and POST's including authentication. Ideally I would like to create an extension that handles all of the required logic and call it as a custom command

Comment: you can write a shell script and put all logic in it and call it from Dockerfile

Comment: Would this be executed in the container or outside of the container? Assume this could also be Python or Golang ?

Comment: It will be inside container. I edited the answer with example.

Comment: Thanks - I assume however a single copy of the script can be stored outside of the container and used during the build for all containers ?

Comment: I will need to check on that if it is possible. If you do not need the file after work is done, you can remove the file ( add RUN rm file) from Dockerfile, which will clean the container.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are referring to download some files using http (HTTP GET) as one of the example in the question. You can try this.

```
RUN wget https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
```

or

```
RUN curl https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
```

The example Dockerfile with download shell script

```
PROJ-DIR
    - files
        - test.sh
    - Dockerfile
```

files/test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

wget https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest

COPY files/test.sh /opt/
RUN chmod u+x /opt/test.sh

RUN rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY*
RUN yes | yum install wget

RUN /opt/test.sh
RUN rm /opt/test.sh
```

Build the image

```
docker build -t test_img .
```